# Is there a way to have a table created in the master available to all users and databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have zipcode data that I would like to create a table in the master database and make available to all my databases, for instance:

```
MYSQLSERVER -> Databases -> System Databases -> Master -> Table -> Zipcode_data
```

and I would like query it as follows

```
SELECT * 
FROM master.dbo.zipcode_data
```

from any of my projects databases, if this possible, give the other databases permission to just query a table created in the master?

Comment: Is there a reason to put this specifically into the master database, and not just its own user database called something like "shared_data"?

Comment: Do not put your stuff in Master, it's a bad idea.  The way to do what you want above is 1) Create a new database called, let's say `[Common]`. Then in your projects database use Synonyms to redirect `dbo.zipcode_data` references from your projects database to your `[Common]` database.

Comment: Generally speaking, putting user objects in `master` is the wrong choice. Yes, you *can* put them in there, but that doesn't mean you should. Also `dbo.master.zipcode_data ` would reference an object called `zipcode_data` on the **schema** `master` in a database called `dbo`.

Comment: You shouldn't mess with the system databases like `master`. You can simply create a new (user) database that holds the objects. Or look into schemas.

Comment: The reason is not to have the zipcode_data table duplicated in all my projects databases. Thanks IMSoP.

Comment: It's possible but NOT recommended and it's not a best practice. 
If you want to query from a table called zipcode_data in a schema dbo from master (system database), you should change your query from 

SELECT * FROM dbo.master.zipcode_data => SELECT * FROM master.dbo.zipcode_data

Comment: Hi Larnu thanks for you reply, sorry I meant SELECT * FROM master.dbo.zipcode_data.

Comment: Thanks sticky bit, that is exactly how I currently have it I created a database with one single table zipcode_data just to query value from my other databases, but I thought that I could accomplish it by just creating the table in the master database and query from it SELECT * FROM master.dbo.zipcode_data and of course permission must be applied in order for the table to be available to all other databases.

Comment: @JoseSaiz why do you think that having a table in one database is better than having it in another? You could put it in any of the current databases and use it in your queries, you don't need a new database. As for permissions, that's another reason to *avoid* `master`. You really don't want to give anyone write permissions to `master` without a very serious reason. Which means no account will be able to write to that table.